# Ошибка при выполнении запроса к MySQL в Python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

При проверке своего кода, встретился с ошибкой `pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')` или же с ошибкой об внезапном прекращении соединения с БД. Причём появляется она очень странно. Отправляется несколько последовательных запросов и шестой или седьмой из них выдаёт ошибку.
Запросы вида: `SELECT state FROM chats WHERE id = 732511`

Я прочитал, что такое происходит, если я использую глобальный курсор или закрываю преждевременно его, но в моём коде такого нет:

```py
def get_columns(connection, table, search_column, search_value, *columns, cursor_class = EvalDictCursor):
    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_class)

        request = f'SELECT ' + ', '.join(columns) + f' FROM {table} WHERE {search_column} = %s'

        cursor.execute(request, (search_value, ))

        answer = cursor.fetchone()

        cursor.close()

    if answer is not None:
        return answer
    else:
        return {}
```

Ещё в одном посте увидел, что проблема в глобальном соединении, но если я буду его создавать каждый раз заново, то тогда время выполнения сильно затянется. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Что содержится в аргументе connection?

Comment: Заранее созданное подключение к БД.

Comment: А вы уверены, что оно открыто?

Comment: Я только что проверил. Я его создаю в начале и потом только передаю в функции, никак не изменяю. С самим соединением всё хорошо, так как я уже сказал, что первые запросы отправляются нормально

Comment: Ну в части опубликованного кода ошибок точно нет, ищете в другом месте

Comment: А в какую сторону мне хотя бы идти? Сейчас проверил все курсоры, все после выполнения закрываю, а ничего другого криминального не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Погуглив ещё немного, я узнал, что проблема может быть в многопоточности. А так как у меня этот код разработан для бота, который её поддерживает, то из-за этого вылезала ошибка.

Что бы её исправить, нужно или отказаться от много-ти или делать для каждого потока отдельное соединение (по крайней мере, так было написано, сам ещё не проверял).